# System Versioned (Temporal) tables in a view

Tags: sql-server, temporal-tables

I have a number of joined "system versioned" tables, e.g. Person, PhoneNumber and EmailAddress
The Person will only have one PhoneNumber and one EmailAddress at a time.

The PhoneNumber and EmailAddress will not **usually** be updated outside of a transaction that updates all 3 at once. (But they **can** be updated independently, just not in the normal scenario) 
E.g. if I change the phone number, then all 3 records will be issued an update in the same transaction, hence giving them all the same "start time" in the history table.

Let's say I insert a person and then change the person's name, email address and phone number in 2 transactions:

```sql
DECLARE @Id TABLE(ID INT)
DECLARE @PersonId INT

-- Initial insert
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO Person (Name) OUTPUT inserted.PersonId INTO @Id VALUES ('Homer') 
    SELECT @PersonId = Id FROM @Id
    INSERT INTO EmailAddress (Address, PersonId) VALUES ('homer@fake', @PersonId)
    INSERT INTO PhoneNumber (Number, PersonId) VALUES ('999', @PersonId)
COMMIT TRANSACTION

-- Update 
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02'

BEGIN TRANSACTION
    UPDATE Person SET Name = 'Kwyjibo' WHERE PersonID = @PersonId
    UPDATE EmailAddress SET Address = 'kwyjibo@fake'  WHERE PersonID = @PersonId
    UPDATE PhoneNumber SET Number = '000'  WHERE PersonID = @PersonId
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Now I select from the view (just an inner join of the tables) using a temporal query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM vwPerson FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL 
WHERE PersonId = @PersonId
ORDER BY SysStartTime DESC
```

And I get returned a row for every combination of edit!

[image: Multi rows]

How can I query this view (if at all possible) to only return 1 row for the updates that were made in the same transaction?
I could add a WHERE clause to match all the SysStartTimes, however that would exclude those cases where a table was updated independently of the other 2.

Comment: Temporal tables do not change on each transaction - they change on each `UPDATE` or `DELETE` - even if the `UPDATE` didn't change anytthing (e.g. `UPDATE foo SET col = 'A' WHERE col = 'A'` will still cause rows to be added to the history table). It sounds like you want to cull the history table to reduce "noisy" rows, in which case that's an entirely different question.

Comment: No, I'm happy with 'noisy' rows (ie updates that didn't update anything).  What I'm not happy with is that querying a regular view doesn't return a single row for updates to all 3 table that happened at the same time (SysStartTime is guaranteed to be the same in a single transaction).  See that the top row of the results is how it ended up, and the next 3 rows are combinations of different states. I was hoping it would be smart enough to realise that it was all part of the same transaction of updates and not show the rows 2 to 4

Answer (score 0):

Because of the independent updates, you actually first have to "reconstruct" a timeline, onto which you can join the data. A "sketch" of this follows, obviously don't have your actual table defns so untested:

```
;WITH AllTimes as (
     SELECT PersonId,SysStartTime as ATime FROM Person
     UNION
     SELECT PersonId,SysEndTime FROM Person
     UNION
     SELECT PersonId,SysStartTime FROM EmailAddress
     UNION
     SELECT PersonId,SysEndTime FROM EmailAddress
     UNION
     SELECT PersonId,SysStartTime FROM PhoneNumber
     UNION
     SELECT PersonId,SysEndTime FROM PhoneNumber
), Ordered as (
     SELECT
        PersonId, ATime, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonId ORDER BY Atime) rn
     FROM
        AllTimes
), Intervals as (
    SELECT
       p1.PersonId,
       o1.ATime as StartTime,
       o2.ATime as EndTime
    FROM
       Ordered o1
          inner join
       Ordered o2
          on
              o1.PersonId = o2.PersonId and
              o1.rn = o2.rn - 1
)
SELECT
    * --TODO - Columns
FROM
   Intervals i
      inner join
   Person p
      on
          i.PersonId = p.PersonId and
          i.StartTime < p.SysEndTime and
          p.SysStartTime < i.EndTime
      inner join
   Email e
      on
          i.PersonId = e.PersonId and
          i.StartTime < e.SysEndTime and
          e.SysStartTime < i.EndTime
      inner join
   PhoneNumber pn
      on
          i.PersonId = pn.PersonId and
          i.StartTime < pn.SysEndTime and
          pn.SysStartTime < i.EndTime
```

With appropriate filters if you just want one persons details, the optimizer will hopefully work it out. There may be additional filters for the joins that I've missed out also.

Hopefully you can see how the 3 CTEs construct the timeline. We take advantage of `UNION` eliminating duplicates in the first one.

Comment: I tried this out (needed to change p1.PersonId to o1.PersonId) but otherwise the query runs.  It doesn't perform any temporal query though, so I only get the latest version on any record.